# PF Wizard does not go to the next step?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, wizard

I have implemented the following wizard:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">

<h:head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form id="wizard" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:wizard id="wiz" widgetVar="wiz">


            <p:tab id="productWizardBasicTab"
                title="#{lang['product.TabBasicProduct']}">
                <p:panel header="#{lang['product.header']}">
                    <h:panelGrid id="basic" columns="2" columnClasses="label, value"
                        styleClass="grid">
                        <h:outputText value="#{lang['product.productname']}" />
                        <p:inputText id="productName" required="true" label="" value="" />

                        <h:outputText value="#{lang['product.description']}" />
                        <p:inputText id="productDescription" required="true" label=""
                            value="" />

                        <h:outputText value="#{lang['product.tags']}" />
                        <p:inputText id="productTags" required="true" label="" value="" />

                        <h:outputText value="#{lang['product.price']}" />
                        <p:inputText id="productPrice" required="true" label="" value="" />

                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="productWizardImageTab"
                title="#{lang['product.TabProductImages']}">
                <p:panel header="#{lang['product.UploadImageHeader']}">

                </p:panel>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="productWizardSpecialTab"
                title="#{lang['product.TabSpezialization']}">

            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="productWizardTagTab"
                title="#{lang['product.TabTags']}">

            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="productWizardTagTab"
                title="#{lang['product.ShareTab']}">

            </p:tab>

        </p:wizard>
    </h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

My problem is, that this wizard, does when started on a `tomcat 7.0 server` does not react. I have implemented the lib of `PF 3.5` and use `jsf 2.2.0`.

I am thankfully for every hint on the wizard!

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not completely sure that PF3.5 supports JSF2.2, the following excerpt will cause validation to fail on your form.

```
<p:inputText id="productName" required="true" label="" value="" />
```

`value=""` means that the value is not bound to any backing bean property, and on this condition, the wizard will fail to proceed. It's weird, I know, but the component somehow expects to be able to update the value on that component against another component. As your form stands, simply entering a value in that text field without it being updated against something else will still result in a validation error (due to `required="true"`).

So you need to bind those fields to something updatable, preferably on a backing bean.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Primefaces 3.5 won't work with jsf 2.2.0. If you see your tomcat console you can find out. And second thing is bind the value with a backing bean property.
Use jsf 2.1.22. or above(not 2.2.0 or above) with primefaces 3.5 to get the primefaces wizard working.

If you want to continue using jsf 2.2.0 or above use primefaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be, that you are using the same `id` and `widgetVar` for the `p:wizard`. Some browser mix them up, and then try to execute `wiz.nextStep()` on the `id` instead of the `widgetVar` which results in some kind of "nextStep() is not a function" error.